# Masses of 500 Internal Server Error in Console (Chrome)

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-500

I have a little website.

When I open the Console (Inspect the Site) I get many, many `500`s (Internal Server Error).

I don't know what this is.

> GET http://stuffs.000webhostapp.com/cs.php?cookie=lang=en;%20PHPSESSID=khlinm290q0t698copmik6cp12;%20_ga=GA1.2.375876183.1488986657 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is it. I get all seconds like around 100 of these errors... It crashed my console. And I don't find it on my site when I search in files...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be a file permission issue.

So please give the necessary permissions to your files and try to execute again.

Please confirm all the files that shows in the console is the file in your server.

Otherwise these error log may be because of some malware .

Please check it it once. May be calling some of your js file or any unwanted library included in your coding. Please avoid that call any js file from third party . Download it and the use it as local file.